# Were the identities of the Final Five planned from the start?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004, cylon

I was just rewatching some random episodes, including "33", the very first episode of season 1. The theme of the episode centers around exhaustion, and they make a point to show that Boomer was holding up far better than people around her, even jokingly saying that maybe she's a Cylon, which is actually true.

That said, I also noticed that two other characters are holding up really well - Saul Tigh and Galen Tyrol. While everyone in the CIC and on the flight deck are barely standing on their legs, some are openly sleeping, but those two were still both literally and figuratively running around and doing their duties, Tigh even skipping his turn(s) to sleep just so Adama could sleep instead.

Boomer is our confirmation that exhaustion gets to Cylons far, far slower than humans. Aside from Boomer, only Tigh and Tyrol were holding up relatively well. Does that mean their identities were planned from day 1?

Also, Saul Tigh was featured in a Season 2 blooper reel as "Number 13"

Comment: Could've sworn this had been asked before, but I guess not.

Comment: I would be shocked if they planned it out that far, but that's some pretty interesting evidence.

Comment: Though both, Tigh and Tyrol, hold high positions as XO and chief of hangar (as in, a big part of their defense), so it is understandable that only people who can endure high stress situations will be promoted to those positions, but sure that is not really an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this 2009 [interview](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/Full-Interview-With-Battlestar-Galactica-Ron-Moore-David-Eick-14472.html), identities weren't decided until later in the series:

> **How did you choose who the final five Cylons would be? Was it like picking a name out of a hat? Or did you have it from the very beginning?**
>
> [...]
>
> **Ron Moore:** Yes, it was a little of both. I mean the final four came up literally in a moment in a writer's room where we were struggling with the end of season three. [...] I said, I just wish that there was, we had some bigger revelation here. I just said, you know, I just got this image of like four of our people walking from different areas of the ship and all ending up in one room together.
>
> They all close the doors and they look at each other. And they say, okay we're Cylon. And then we just reveal like four of them, you know, in one fell swoop.
>
> Then settling on the last one. We kind of had a good idea going into the last season who the final Cylon was. And, but we were willing to sort of, you know, look at other candidates and see who it could be and which one makes the most sense in the mythology. Ultimately we stuck with the original choice because it just made the most sense in terms of the history of the show and what it means for the characters.

Supported by comments in [another interview](https://www.comicmix.com/2008/05/20/battlestar-galactica-interview-mark-verheiden-on-the-final-five-and-music/) with Mark Verheiden:

> The question of “who” was something we discussed at length when we started considering this revelation for season three. Stories and plotlines tend to evolve as a show goes on, so I personally think even if Ron Moore and David Eick had picked five names in the beginning, they may well have changed as the show went on.